# Android Brightcove video player

Tags: java, android, url, video, brightcove

I did a sample code for Bright Cove video player for Android application. I did it with a static URL. I am confuse how to play video using video id. I have posted full code below.

```
//URL of the video we are playing
private static final String VIDEO_URL = "http://cf9c36303a9981e3e8cc-31a5eb2af178214dc2ca6ce50f208bb5.r97.cf1.rackcdn.com/lucy_gets_shot_1280x720.mp4";

//String array of ad URLS
private static final String[] googleAds = {
        "http://pubads.g.doubleclick.net/gampad/ads?" +
        "sz=400x300&iu=%2F6062%2Fhanna_MA_group%2Fvideo_comp_app&ciu_szs=&impl=s&gdfp_req=1&" +
        "env=vp&output=xml_vast2&unviewed_position_start=1&m_ast=vast&url=[referrer_url]&" +
        "correlator=[timestamp]",
        "http://ad.doubleclick.net/pfadx/CABdemoSite;kw=acb;sz=728x90;ord=29078349023890482394823;dcmt=text/xml",
        "http://pubads.g.doubleclick.net/gampad/ads?sz=400x300&iu=%2F6062%2Fhanna_MA_group%2Fwrapper_with_comp&ciu_szs=728x90&impl=s&gdfp_req=1&env=vp&output=xml_vast2&unviewed_position_start=1&m_ast=vast&url=[referrer_url]&correlator=[timestamp]",
    };

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Get the video view
    final BrightcoveVideoView videoView = (BrightcoveVideoView) findViewById(R.id.video_view);

    MediaController controller = new MediaController(this);
    videoView.setMediaController(controller);

    //Initialize the Brightcove Google IMA Component 
    GoogleIMAComponent comp = new GoogleIMAComponent(videoView, videoView.getEventEmitter());

    //Setup our event listeners
    setupEventListeners(videoView);

    //Add a video!
    videoView.add(Video.createVideo(VIDEO_URL));
}

private void setupEventListeners(final BrightcoveVideoView videoView) {

    /*
     * DID_SET_VIDEO is a good place to set up cue points.
     * For advertising, we have hard coded some advertising URLs from Doubleclick
     * 
     * To start the advertising process, we need to create cue points that represent
     * where the advertising exists, in this case we are going to create a 
     * pre/mid/post roll
     */
    videoView.getEventEmitter().on(EventType.DID_SET_VIDEO, new EventListener(){

        public void processEvent(Event event) {
            //Reference to eventEmitter
            EventEmitter eventEmitter = videoView.getEventEmitter();

            final String cuePointType = "ad";

            //Create some objects to help us manage the metadata
            ArrayList<CuePoint> points = new ArrayList<CuePoint>();
            CuePoint point = null;
            Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>(); 

            //Pre roll
            properties.put("url", googleAds[1]);    
            point = new CuePoint(PositionType.BEFORE, cuePointType, properties);
            points.add(point);

            //Mid roll
            properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            properties.put("url", googleAds[2]);
            point = new CuePoint(10000, cuePointType, properties);
            points.add(point);

            //Post roll
            properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            properties.put("url", googleAds[0]);
            point = new CuePoint(PositionType.AFTER, cuePointType, properties);
            points.add(point);

            //Create details for the cuepoints
            Map<String, Object> details = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            details.put(Event.CUE_POINTS, points);

            /*
             * Emit that we are setting cuepoints, this will allow all components to respond
             * that are interested in listening
             */
            eventEmitter.emit(EventType.SET_CUE_POINTS, details);
        }
    });

    /*
     * ADS_REQUEST_FOR_VIDEO is the Brightcove Google IMA plugin event that gets fired when
     * there is an ads request for a video.  This will allow you to use your cue point data
     * and respond to the event with ads.  Having this hook allows you to do any additional 
     * configuration of companion ads or application logic for the ads. 
     * 
     */
    videoView.getEventEmitter().on(GoogleIMAEventType.ADS_REQUEST_FOR_VIDEO, new EventListener() {

        public void processEvent(Event event) {

            EventEmitter eventEmitter = videoView.getEventEmitter();
            List<CuePoint> cuePoints = (List<CuePoint>) event.properties.get(Event.CUE_POINTS);
            ArrayList<SimpleAdsRequest> ads = new ArrayList<SimpleAdsRequest>(cuePoints.size());

            for(CuePoint point : cuePoints) {
                //Create an ad request
                SimpleAdsRequest adRequest = new SimpleAdsRequest();

                //Set up a companion slot
                Collection<CompanionAdSlot> adSlots = new HashSet<CompanionAdSlot>();
                CompanionAdSlot adSlot = new CompanionAdSlot();

                //View group and size
                ViewGroup adCompanionViewGroup = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.ad_frame);
                adSlot.setContainer(adCompanionViewGroup);
                adSlot.setSize(728, 90);

                adSlots.add(adSlot);
                adRequest.setCompanions(adSlots);

                //URL and Type
                adRequest.setAdTagUrl(point.getStringProperty("url"));
                adRequest.setAdType(AdType.VIDEO);

                ads.add(adRequest);
            }  

            //Respond to the event
            event.properties.put(GoogleIMAComponent.ADS_REQUESTS, ads);
            eventEmitter.respond(event);
        } 
    });

    /*
     * SET_CUE_POINTS is an event signaling that cue points are being set on the video
     * We will use this as a cue point (pun intended) to play the video
     */
    videoView.getEventEmitter().on(EventType.SET_CUE_POINTS, new EventListener() {

        public void processEvent(Event arg0) {
            //Play on player...
            videoView.getEventEmitter().emit(EventType.PLAY);
        }
    });

    videoView.getEventEmitter().on(GoogleIMAEventType.DID_BEGIN_PLAYING_AD, new EventListener() {

        @Override
        public void processEvent(Event arg0) {
            Log.v(TAG, arg0.properties.toString());
            //Check here to see if you want to hide / show the companion ad
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Catalog](http://docs.brightcove.com/en/video-cloud/brightcove-player-sdk-for-android/reference/versions/4.0.21/index.html) to fetch a video by video ID.

```
Catalog catalog = new Catalog("BRIGHTCOVE MEDIA API TOKEN");
catalog.findVideoByID("1234567890", new VideoListener() {
  @Override
  public void onVideo(Video video) {
    videoView.add(video);
  }
  @Override
  public void onError(String error) {
    // Handle error
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you... I found it from here http://docs.brightcove.com/en/video-cloud/brightcove-player-sdk-for-android/guides/android-sdk-quick-start.html

Comment: It plays a single video which id is given. i want to play all the video from a account. Can you help me what to do?